# Reversing an RSA function throws pkcs decoding error

Tags: ida, decryption, encryption, cryptography, openssl

I'm working my way through reversing a toy challenge, and I find myself stuck. The app is pretty simple, it spits out a blob of text (e.g. "3b880a90e476d66569d9d5dfb5cd755af3f..."). Dumping the code, I can see that it builds an RSA public key by directly specifying `n` and `e`:

```
myRsa->n=v4;
myRsa->e=v5;
```

Then it encrypts it's payload:

```
encodedLength = RSA_public_encrypt(flen, from, to, myRsa, 1);
...
printf("%s",to);
```

My goal: steal the payload. Debugging tells me flen is 240, encodedLength is 100. I dumped the `e` for the public key as bytes, and wrote some code to generate my own RSA public/private key, patching `e` to be mine (`n` is the same for both, so left unpatched).

```
unsigned long bytes_read = fread(in, sizeof(unsigned char), size, file);
    fclose(file);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < bytes_read; i++) {
        if (memcmp(nCharOrig, in + i, 258) == 0) {
            memcpy(in + i, nCharNew, 258);
            printf("Found and patched at %d\n", i);
        };
    }
```

Patch works, I get a different blob of text, which in theory is the same payload, encrypted with my public key. So I try to decrypt it:

```
unsigned char output[8000];
    RSA *rsa = RSA_new();
    EVP_PKEY *privkey;
    FILE *fp;

    privkey = EVP_PKEY_new();
    fp = fopen ("private.pem", "r");
    PEM_read_PrivateKey( fp, &privkey, NULL, NULL);
    fclose(fp);

    rsa = EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(privkey);
    int decryptLength = RSA_private_decrypt(256, input, output, rsa, 1);
```

Weirdly I get back decryptLength = -1, and an error:
`error:0407109F:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:pkcs decoding error`

I'm at a loss.. what am I missing here?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the keys you generated are valid? (`openssl verify`)

Comment: Can you share your toy challenge? Also whats the value of `e`?

Comment: If you're able to patch the app, is there a reason you can't patch it to dump the unencrypted payload instead? Either that or get the unencrypted payload via the debugger?

Comment: @hairlessbear I actually did steal it via debugger, that was easy :) Doing it this way as a challenge to myself to finally understand openssl/RSA code reversing correctly.

Comment: @MegaTonnage yep, wrote them out to files using the openssl api, and verified them as good -- both the old stolen e/n and new ones I generated.

Comment: What's unclear to me is does the goal include that the program still performs the original task, too? Otherwise why not patch `RSA_public_encrypt()` "out" and replace it by code that writes the plain text to disk, say? Also, it's not clear what the details of the "app" are. For example, does this app link OpenSSL dynamically? If so, for Windows you could try a DLL placement attack, for Linux something like setting `LD_PRELOAD` and writing your own wrapper for [RSA_public_encrypt](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man3/RSA_public_encrypt.html). You may have to provide stubs for others.

Comment: That said, does your replacement key have the same properties (length etc) as the original? And the message you put in, do you keep it within the size range observed during debugging? Clearly OpenSSL is complaining about the padding (`#define RSA_PKCS1_PADDING 1`). This particular mode also carries a warning (link in prev. comment). Have you tried using `RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING` (== 4) instead of `RSA_PKCS1_PADDING`? It'd be the first thing before I try to dig deeper into OpenSSL logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out if you're gonna get hex strings printed to console, you have to convert them back to a binary char array before decrypting..